# Can I use C++0x to game programming on xxx platform?

Tags: c++11, game-engine

I'm developing a cross platform game engine this targets Windows, Linux, Mac, Mobiles(Android, iOS) and Consoles(PS3, Xbox360). I'm considering C++0x in role of the core and native language. What platforms above support C++0x?.

Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me, but if you were developing for all those platforms you would know the answer.

Comment: What kind of "game engine"? 3D shooter? RPG? Platformer? Puzzle-bases? Browser-based? You need to define your specifications before you can determine which language to use.

Comment: @Axel Gneiting: Currently I develop only on Windows and Linux but I will expand it later. I'm sure C++ will able but not sure about C++0x. That is why I ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to be bound by your API for drawing.

- Windows - Yes, DirectX, OpenGL
- Linux - Yes, OpenGL
- Mac - Yes, OpenGL
- Andriod - No (Java), OpenGL
- iOS - No (Objective-C), OpenGL
- PS3 - Yes, OpenGL
- XBox 360 - Yes and No (Yes, for native which means you need distribution rights; No if you're going through XBox Live Arcade which requires C#/XNA)  Both types will use DirectX, XNA will abstract all of your DX calls though.

I would suggest visiting a few sites such as www.gamedev.net to learn what it actually takes to create a game; let alone a game that would be cross platform like you are suggesting.

EDIT:
Updated Windows and Andrio to use OpenGL.

Comment: Actually, OpenGL is available on all listed platforms except XBox.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

Comment: Yes, Windows uses OpenGL but DirectX is much easier to work with.  Regardless you are correct.  Andriod was the only one that I was not sure about.  Thanks for the information; will edit.

Comment: Thanks but what I want to ask is "Does compilers on platforms above support C++0x?". I already known how to develop a game engine and how to make it cross platform.

Comment: Only your host OS' will contain compilers (Windows, Linux, Mac); all others will require the compiled binary to be installed and run.  One can make the claim that you could have a PS3 with Linux on it that you could then have g++ on, but that would again fall under the Linux platform at that point.